# Jersey/Grizzly "Getting Started" example on Linux/Windows or MacOS

Tags: jersey, grizzly

From the the maven "Getting started" example (jersey/grizzly "Got it!") on Mac OS (OS X yosemite 10.10.2 java 1.7.025) I generate a self executable jar that run perfectly fine on Mac OS (either over curl or with the browser). But then if I run the same jar on Windows (Windows 7 entreprise 64 bits java 1.7.0.60) or on Linux (Suse x86_64 3.0.101-0 java 1.7.0) I get a 404 answer with the browser and with wget/curl from GET http://localhost:8080/my_app/myresource but the correct application.wasl file (GET http://localhost:8080/my_app/application.wadl).

Has someone already observed this behaviour by running the same code on different OS ? Any hints where to search ?

In advance many thanks for your help

Kind regards

Antoine

Comment: Should be `myapp` not `my_app`, if you haven't made any changes to the original archetype

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more of a reference for Windows 7 6.1 64bit Java 1.7.0_65 (works fine)

> `C:\temp>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 \
>   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false \
>   -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example \
>   -DarchetypeVersion=2.17`
>
> `C:\temp>cd simple-service`
>
> `C:\temp>simple-service> mvn package`
>
> `C:\temp>simple-service>mvn exec:java
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building simple-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ simple-service >>>
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ simple-service <<<
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ simple-service ---
>   Mar 29, 2015 1:33:55 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
>   INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8080]
>   Mar 29, 2015 1:33:55 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
>   INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
>   Jersey app started with WADL available at http://localhost:8080/myapp/application.wadl
>   Hit enter to stop it...`

cURL

> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource
>   Got it!`

For running jar, added these two plugins

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <index>true</index>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Repackage and run

> `C:\temp\simple-service>mvn clean package`
>
> `C:\temp\simple-service>java -jar target/simple-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   Mar 29, 2015 1:38:54 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
>   INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8080]
>   Mar 29, 2015 1:38:54 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
>   INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
>   Jersey app started with WADL available at http://localhost:8080/myapp/application.wadl
>   Hit enter to stop it...`
>
> `C:\>curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource
>   Got it!`